# Accessing codeigniter session variables inside javascript

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

How to access codeigniter session variables inside javascript? If I create session variable inside plain php and access it in javascript it gives me result but in case of codeigniter session variables it gives me syntax error.

I use following code of line to access codeigniter session variable in my .js file

```
var m1  = "<?php echo json_encode($this->session->userdata('max_age')); ?>";
```

Comment: That looks correct to me.  What's the problem?

Comment: it gives me syntax error on next line

Comment: Error on next line? So, what's in the next line?

Comment: If this is supposed to be a JSON variable, you might not want the quotes around the object.

Comment: sorry, in my original code there is no quotes.But it gives me syntax error on next line. Sorry for my poor english. I m very thankful to u all who gives me suggestions.

Comment: helllo  Damien Pirsy next line there is normal java script code

Comment: if i comment above code then it will error free

Comment: but i want to access session variables inside javas cript.Is there any another way for accessing it?

Comment: What does the outputted HTML look like (in the browser). If there are no quotes around your PHP output and the output is empty you are left with var m1 = ;  which causes an error.

Comment: ok.But it is not working

Comment: @RajneelJoshi You need to show us all of the code that causes the error, not just the line you want to work a certain way. Also, http://translate.google.com/ might be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

> "I use following code of line to access codeigniter session variable in
>   my **.js file**
>   "

---

You cannot put PHP code inside your .js file. It will not be parsed. You must put your code in the PHP file that your .js file is being called from.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var m1  = <?php echo json_encode($this->session->userdata('max_age')); ?>; 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments above, the problem is most likely caused by an empty php echo output.  You stated above that you DO NOT have quotes around your echo statement.  So in your code it looks like this:

```
var m1  = <?php echo json_encode($this->session->userdata('max_age')); ?>;
```

This might be a problem if your php variable `$this->session->userdata('max_age')` is empty.  Because if that is the case, json_encode will output an empty string.  Please do a "View Source" in your browser and look if that line looks like this:

```
var m1  = ;
```

If it does, you found your problem.  The above is invalid and would cause the syntax error.